Jaeger collector and Jaeger Query with Opensearch(Elasticsearch) - UI not showing spans
I've deployed Jaeger collector and Jaeger Query from the all-in-one image with opensearch (Opensearch 6.2 AWS) as storage. When the application sends the telemetry, it is received in the opensearch indexes - jaeger-span-write and jaeger-service-write, but nothing is showed to the jaeger UI. As I know, the jaeger collector should store the data in indexes in the fowling format: jaeger-span-2023-04-27. No specific arguments are provided for the Jaeger collector and Jaeger Query. How can i fixed this issue?

You'll need to provide some level of config to jaeger-query for it to authenticate and query the OpenSearch instance you are running. Since you haven't provided config details I will use an example here
jaeger-query \
  --span-storage.type=elasticsearch \
  --es.server-urls=http://localhost:9200 \
  --es.index-prefix=jaeger-span \
  --es.username=<your_username> \
  --es.password=<your_password>

Also feel free to ask on the CNCF Slack in #jaeger and we can help you more. Be aware that we are close to the release of Jaeger v2 which uses YAML files similar to the OpenTelemetry collector. This example is for Jaeger v1.
